# "Not a valid string." - error when trying save dict to TextField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code in my **models.py**:

```
class ApiLog(models.Model):
...
incoming_data = models.TextField('incoming data', null=True, blank=True)
```

In **serializers.py**

```
class ApiLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ApiLog
        fields = ('incoming_data',)
```

In **views.py**:

```
class ApiLogViewSet(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ApiLogSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

In POST-request I send:

```
data = {..., 
        'incoming_data':{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
       }
```

When in view trying **serializer.is_valid()** I have error:

```
{"incoming_data":["Not a valid string."]}
```

Maybe it's because I try to save dictionary to TextField?

Is it possible to save this dictionary to TextField? Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There are two solutions, either use JSONField in models or stringify your dict (for example using JSON.strinfigy() function in JavaScript)

Comment: `data.update({'incoming_data': str(data.get('incoming_data'))})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your serializer:

```
class ApiLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    incoming_data = serializers.JSONField() # change is here

    class Meta:
        model = ApiLog
        fields = ('incoming_data',)
```

This will convert your `JSON` dict to string and store in DB as `Text`.

Refer to the [official DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) for more details

Comment: Hi, this worked fine for me. However does this support both reading the data and writing ? In my case, writing is ok but it is not reading as expected. Any suggestion please help

Answer (score 0):

try with quotes?:

```
data = {..., 
        'incoming_data':'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
       }
```